# Custom UIButton -> part of title disappears after click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I created custom button subclassing UIButton.
I set custom font for titleLabel.

After tapping on custom button, the part of title disappears.

Without setting custom font, the text stays the same.

I think this problem only occures with devices targeting ios >= 13.

Before tap ->
[image]

After tap ->[image]

//BasicButton class

```
class BasicButton: UIButton {
    


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.proximaNovaBold.withSize(20.0)
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.proximaNovaBold.withSize(20.0)
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.proximaNovaBold.withSize(20.0)
        layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    
    override func setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControl.State) {
        super.setTitle(title, for: state)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.proximaNovaBold.withSize(20.0)
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

//extension UIFont

```
@nonobjc class var proximaNovaBold: UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Bold", size: 17.0)!
    }
```

//storyboard
[image]

//BasicButton storyboard properties

[image]]
[image]

Comment: chage Type of button to Custom

Comment: change ***Style*** of the button from **Plain** to **Default**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing Style of the button from Plain to Default was solution for the problem